# I appendChild(form input) so how would i remove the new inputs from last first?

Tags: javascript

i have made a function to add new upload and description inputs onClick. How would i make a function to remove the created elements from the bottom to top?

```
var i = 1;

function add()
{
    var element = document.createElement('input')
    var element1 = document.createElement('input')
    var space = document.createElement('br')
    var des = document.createElement('span')

    var td = document.getElementById('upload')

    des.innerHTML = "Description: "
    element.setAttribute("type", "text")
    element.setAttribute("name", "desciption"+ i)
    element.setAttribute("value", " ")
    element1.setAttribute("type", "file")
    element1.setAttribute("name", "uploadFile"+ i)
    element1.setAttribute("id", "uploadFile"+ i)

    td.appendChild(des)
    td.appendChild(element)
    td.appendChild(element1)
    td.appendChild(space)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
> element.setAttribute("type", "text")
```

It is more reliable to set values for standard properties directly:

```
 element.type = "text";
```

Anyhow, you can remove the elements using:

```
   td.removeChild(space);      
   td.removeChild(element1);
   td.removeChild(element);
   td.removeChild(des);
```

or you can do:

```
  var nodes = td.childNodes;
  var i = nodes.length;
  while (i--) {
    td.removeChild(nodes[i]);
  }
```

or more simply:

```
  td.innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: I tired to use the td.removeChild and i keep getting an error. td.removeChild(space);
 Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

Comment: Are you calling it from the same function, or another? if it's from a different function, the variables may not be in scope so `space` is undefined. Use one of the other methods suggested above instead.

Comment: i made a new function with all the variables in it 
`function remove()
{
 //create an input type dynamically
 var element = document.createElement('input');
 var element1 = document.createElement('input');
 var space = document.createElement('br');
 var des = document.createElement('span');
 //append the element in page (td)
 var td = document.getElementById('upload');
  
 
   td.removeChild(space);      
   td.removeChild(element1);
   td.removeChild(element);
   td.removeChild(des);
 
 i--; 
 
}`